# Splunk REST API Post route is throwing Cannot perform action "POST" without a target name to act on .net core

Tags: c#, .net, splunk

I am trying to create a role using splunk REST API (https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.5/RESTREF/RESTaccess#authorization.2Froles). The route works perfectly using postman, but when I try to invoke the same route using IServiceClient via .net core, I run in to "Cannot perform action "POST" without a target name to act on". Please let me know what other information I can provide. Have been searching on google for the error and in splunk documentation with no luck.

```
using (var client = _serviceClientFactory.GetServiceClient()) //client service factory returns a ServiceClient
                {
                    PostRoleRequest request = new PostRoleRequest
                    {
                        name = Const.DefaultRoleName //this is the only required param
                    };
                    
                    var response = await client.PostAsync<PostRoleResponse>($"/services/authorization/roles?output_mode=json", request);
                }

 public class PostRoleRequest
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You should capture the request, with Fiddler for instance, and compare it to the request as seen in the Postman console.

Comment: @Crowcoder, I tried that, but for some weird reasons, the fiddler call from inside the API is showing 200 OK where within actual api the call is throwing exception (400 bad request)

Comment: after setting up the fiddler certificate properly, I am able to see the different. My request from API is in Json format where the postman is sending request in application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Do you think that might be the issue?

Comment: I think it is very likely. An API can be implemented to accept multiple mime types but in my experience they usually dictate one specific format.